# Multiple table Join and Query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following OFBiz tables that I want to join using mySQL SQL query:

1. USER_LOGIN
2. PERSON
3. PARTY_CONTACT_MECH
4. CONTACT_MECH
5. TELECOM_NUMBER
6. POSTAL_ADDRESS
7. PARTY

Tables `USER_LOGIN, PERSON` and `PARTY_CONTACT_MECH` all contain the foreign key `"PARTY_ID"` that references the primary key `"PARTY_ID"` in the `PARTY` table.

Tables `PARTY_CONTACT_MECH, TELECOM_NUMBER` and `POSTAL_ADDRESS` all have the foreign key `"CONTACT_MECH_ID"` that references the primary key `"PARTY_ID"` in the table `CONTACT_MECH`.

Since `PARTY_CONTACT_MECH` is also related to the first set of tables listed above on `"PARTY_ID"`, and also related to the second set of tables on `"CONTACT_MECH_ID"`, the two sets or rather all tables can therefore be JOINED on these two keys `"PARTY_ID"` and `"CONTACT_MECH_ID"`.

My question is:

- **How do I join all these tables to query the following fields:**.

.

```
PARTY.PARTY_ID,
USER_LOGIN.USER_LOGIN_ID,
PERSON.FIRST_NAME,
CONTACT_MECH.CONTACT_MECH_ID,
POSTAL_ADDRESS.CITY,
TELECOM_NUMBER.CONTACT_NUMBER.
```

Comment: Could you do a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with your database schema?

Comment: Or just a touch of formatting...

Comment: Since you know that you have keys to JOIN them, what stops you from writing the query?

Comment: You are missing some keys... how is person related to user_login for instance.

Comment: it would be nice if you create an E/R-Diagram

Answer (score 0):

You want to join all tables with their Primary Keys to the Foreign Keys that call the other tables. Foreign keys are essentially the primary keys of other tables. This is so that you use the foreign keys instead of adding excess columns to a table.

On some of your tables, you wanted to join on multiple values. With this, you only need to have your JOIN ON table1.var1 = table2.var2 AND table1.var1 = table3.var3 and vice versa.

You had a lot of tables, so I'll do the best I can:

```
SELECT 
   PARTY.PARTY_ID
   , USER_LOGIN.USER_LOGIN_ID
   , PERSON.FIRST_NAME
   , CONTACT_MECH.CONTACT_MECH_ID
   , POSTAL_ADDRESS.CITY
   , TELECOM_NUMBER.CONTACT_NUMBER
FROM `PARTY`
   JOIN `USER_LOGIN`
     ON PARTY.PARTY_ID = USER_LOGIN.PARTY_ID
   JOIN `PERSON`
     ON PARTY.PARTY_ID = PERSON.PARTY_ID
   JOIN `PARTY_CONTACT_MECH`
     ON PARTY.PARTY_ID = PARTY_CONTACT_MECH.PARTY_ID AND CONTACT_MECH.PARTY_ID = PARTY_CONTACT_MECH.CONTACT_MECH_ID
   JOIN `TELECOM_NUMBER`
     ON CONTACT_MECH.PARTY_ID = TELECOM_NUMBER.CONTACT_MECH_ID
   JOIN `POSTAL_ADDRESS`
     ON CONTACT_MECH.PARTY_ID = POSTAL_ADDRESS.CONTACT_MECH_ID
```

Like I said, it's pretty hard to keep up with all your tables and columns when they aren't visualized, but hopefully, the join statements help you see how to do it.

Comment: this don't work, if tom, dick, and harry whent to the party there is no way that the user_login and person table can tell which of the logins go with which person.  The OP needs to give more information.